# sort a list of objects in Python, based on an attribute (even they are NoneType) of the objects

Tags: python, list, sorting, object

I have invoices list which includes invoice objects.
I want to order these objects according to their date and using below.

```
from operator import attrgetter
invoices_list.sort(key=attrgetter('date'))
```

That's the error I got.

```
TypeError: can't compare FakeDatetime to NoneType
```

I want to do ascending order of the objects according to date and None dates should be first ones. Then others should come with ascending order.

```
$ invoices_list[0].date
$ FakeDatetime(2015, 7, 3, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Show us the content of `invoices_list` maybe?

Comment: Where in the sort order would you like the objects with date equal to `None` to appear?

Comment: It means one of the element in that list has `None ` date

Comment: Yes, I know there is None date. but i wanna order them also. I want None dates shown first, then other dates are coming with ascending order

Answer (score 1):

A simple key wrapper will do the job:

```
class DateKey(object):
    def __init__(self, invoice):
        self.value = invoice.date
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, (datetime.date, type(None))):
            return NotImplemented
        elif self.value is None:
            return True
        elif other.value is None:
            return False
        else:
            return self.value < other.value
```

and then to use it:

```
invoices_list.sort(key=lambda i: DateKey(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom comparison function that knows how to compare `FakeDateTime` and `None` objects, then tell `sort()` to use this function by specifying a `cmp` keyword argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some default value for None (say, 0) you could do something like:

```
invoices_list.sort(key=lambda invoice: invoice.get('date') if (invoice != None) else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified the structure of `FakeDatetime`, I will try to solve your problem with built in `datetime` module.

Basically, you want to sort the list even if the `date` is `None`. In order to do that you have to use a default value when you are getting a `None` date. So, in my solution I take the smallest possible date as the default value when I am getting a `None` date. As as result all elements with `None` date will be put at the top of the sorted list.

```
import datetime

def get_key(d):
    return d.date if hasattr(d, 'date') and d.date is not None else datetime.date(datetime.MINYEAR, 1, 1)

sorted(invoices_list, key=get_key)
```

Comment: `invoices_list[0].date`

`FakeDatetime(2015, 7, 3, 0, 0)`